# Data isn't pulling through from mongoDB into my chart even though I have the JSON data

Tags: node.js, json, charts

I have data saved in my mongoDB which holds players names and scores, I have managed to create a score board with the data outputting (top 10) in DESC order, however for some reason when I use the `name` and the `score` for the x and y axis on my chart, chrome's console error has `score is not defined`?

Any guidance, this has taken me way to long trying to debug this. The score board on the left is working fine, the graph however is not...

**leadership.html**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        //TESTING FOR LEADERSHIP BOARD ********************
        $.get("http://localhost:9000/getPlayersScoreBoard", {}, function (res) {
            let data = res;
            console.log(res);

            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                let name = data[i].name;
                 let score = data[i].score;

                console.log(data[i].name);                                                                                          
                $("#leadership").append("<tr><td class=\"name\">"
                    + data[i].name + "</td><td class=\"score\">" 
                    + data[i].score + "</td></tr>");
            }
        });
    });

    //Bar Chart Leadership Code
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [name],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Leadership Board',
            data: [score],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

[image: console.log]

[image: scoreboard working, graph not]

Comment: Please console.log full node of one row ?

Comment: Where would you like me to pop the console.log?

Comment: You shared console.log not showing all key please share

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar I see, apologies, updated the image above for you ^^

Comment: Please console.log(data)

Comment: console.log(data[i].score);

Comment: Hi @MaheshBhatnagar I popped `console.log(data[i].score);` and in the console the scores all came out correctly

Comment: @K.Haydock your issue is that you're trying to access `name` and `score` outside of the scope - I am working on an example that fixes it

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar Yes, I am so close - as if I place the whole chart code inside of my `for loop` the data pulls through and shows on the chart but the I get 10 different charts laid on top of one another?

Comment: Your problem solved ??

Comment: no :( @MaheshBhatnagar

Comment: @K.Haydock have a look at my answer

Comment: @K.Haydock Please check my answer

Comment: @K.Haydock does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons why you're seeing `score is not defined` is because you're trying to access it outside of the scope - `score` will only be available inside of the `for` loop you've created to generate a table:

```js
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var name = data[i].name
  var score = data[i].score

  // `name` and `score` are available here
}
// `name` and `score` are NOT available here
```

Also, the `chart` expects an array for the `labels` and `data` properties, but in your example, since you're trying to use `name` and `score` variables, they'd only refer to a single item in that array:

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  data: {
    labels: ["David", "Hugo", ...],
    datasets: [{
      data: [55, 30, ...]
    }]
  }
})
```

Here's a solution that fixes your logic. Note that I omitted the stuff that was irrelevant and created a fake API call to try to replicate your example as close as possible:

```js
$(function() {
  get("http://localhost:9000/getPlayersScoreBoard", {}, function(res) {
    function renderTable(items) {
      items.forEach(item => {
        var name = item.name;
        var score = item.score;

        $("#leadership").append(
          '<tr><td class="name">' +
            name +
            '</td><td class="score">' +
            score +
            "</td></tr>"
        );
      });
    }

    function renderChart(items) {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

      var names = items.map(item => item.name);
      var scores = items.map(item => item.score);

      var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "bar",
        data: {
          labels: names,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: "Leadership Board",
              data: scores
            }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      });
    }

    renderTable(res);
    renderChart(res);
  });
});

// Fake `get` request
function get(url, options, callback) {
  function getRandomScore(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
  }
  var data = [
    { _id: 1, name: "David", score: getRandomScore(0, 100) },
    { _id: 1, name: "Hugo", score: getRandomScore(0, 100) },
    { _id: 1, name: "Kayleigh", score: getRandomScore(0, 100) },
    { _id: 1, name: "Craig", score: getRandomScore(0, 100) },
    { _id: 1, name: "Kayz", score: getRandomScore(0, 100) }
  ];
  callback(data);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="leadership"></div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I get `renderTable is not defined`?

Comment: @K.Haydock if you click on the "Run code snippet" button, you will see that it works.  In your code, you're most likely just putting things out of scope when you're trying to call `renderTable` is not defined. I suggest you take everything that's inside of the callback of my `get` request and replace it with the callback you pass to your `$.get` request. Get rid of the code under `/Bar Chart Leadership Code`

Comment: @K.Haydock show me your code with my solution implemented.

Comment: Let me add my code with your solution above in my question......  :)

Comment: @K.Haydock I made an edit in my post, just copy and paste it exactly and just leave out the fake `api` call and make sure to replace the `get` call with `$.get`

Answer (score 1):

We create a function for drawing chart

```
<script>
$(function() {
    //TESTING FOR LEADERSHIP BOARD ********************
    $.get("http://localhost:9000/getPlayersScoreBoard", {}, function (res) {
        let data = res;
        console.log(res);
        let totalLength =  data.length;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            let name = data[i].name;
             let score = data[i].score;

            console.log(data[i].name);  
            if(i ==  totalLength-1)  
            {
               drawChart(data);  
            }                                                                                      
            $("#leadership").append("<tr><td class=\"name\">"
                + data[i].name + "</td><td class=\"score\">" 
                + data[i].score + "</td></tr>");
        }
    });
});

function drawChart(data)
{
    var nameArr = data.map(dataValue => dataValue.name);
    var scoreArr = data.map(dataValue => dataValue.score);
    //Bar Chart Leadership Code
     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: nameArr,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Leadership Board',
            data: scoreArr,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }

});

}
```

Comment: So I tried this and unfortunately I don't get anything show on my page anymore. I get: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: I think it's a `}` to end the function drawChart?

Comment: OK :), so now I have all of the names along the bottom of the axis which is fantastic, but no scores on the bar chart?

Comment: data: scoreArr use that line replace that line data: [scoreArr]

Comment: Hi, so I did that, but still does not work for some reason :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205381/discussion-between-mahesh-bhatnagar-and-k-haydock).

Comment: Ok, I've sent an image of what is coming up via the chat room

Comment: @goto1 can you join a chat & I'll send you what I'm getting?